# C++ factory for composition of template parameters

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, factory, factory-pattern

My question is related to the topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716983/c-composite-template-class-factory).

Suppose I have the following simplified structure:

```
struct Base
{/* ... abstract implementation ...*/};

template<int i>  //simplified. In my real code, some other classes follow. 
struct Derived : public Base
{/* ... implementation ...*/};
```

Now, for instance in order to obtain random creation at runtime, I can set up an easy factory which takes my integer and returns the corresponding base pointer:

```
std::unique_ptr<Base> createDerived(int i)  //again, in the real code, some more enums follow to determine the other classes
{
     if(i==1) {return std::unique_ptr<Derived<1> >(new Derived<1>());}
     else if(i==2) {return std::unique_ptr<Derived<2> >(new Derived<2>());}
     // ...
     else if(i==10000 /*say*/) {return std::unique_ptr<Derived<10000> >(new Derived<10000>());}
}
```

However, in the linked thread, the answerers advise against doing this.

So, my question is why? Is this already what people call bad design? The only disadvantages I see here is that

- the source code may blow up (...however, my classes are "small", i.e. contain only a few and small data members)
- I have to maintain the factory (unless I use some of the clever way for automatic registering which are around).

On the other hand, one can draw all the advantages like flexibility and efficiency of the generic design of the derived class, and also use this whole inheritance-Base-class-pointers-thing if required.

To me it somehow seems like getting the best of both worlds ... what are you thinking?

Comment: Looking at it the other way, why are you trying to justify an architecture that is needlessly complex? A simple member variable will do everything you need it to, in far fewer lines of code.

Comment: Of course, I agree for the given simplified example. But in the real code there are two or three other template variables (classes), which are taken from, e.g., an enum of allowed classes. For this scenario one cannot simply abandon the template-stuff.

Comment: I'm having a hard time thinking of a situation where this pattern would result in a measurable improvement in runtime or compile-time performance, or enhance code readability or maintainability. Perhaps you could link an example?

Comment: Suppose you set up only the class template Derived (with more complicated template parameters), by which you obtain the advantages of generic design (those you mentioned). Fine. The next day, you encounter you also want random generation of the classes. So, add a Base class and set up the factory above, and gain the inheritance stuff without loosing the generic stuff (at the expense of having to explicitly instantiate a number of classes). I'm aware of the non-scalability of this approach, since you can't instantiate 10^20 classes ... but for 10000 it will probably work.